# Hosts manipulation with port number

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, localhost, hosts

I am trying to accomplish a simple task:
Every request with a URI of:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/customers
```

Will also be available through:

```
http://somedomain.com:8081/api/customer
```

I've defined my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com
```

So if the URI is:

```
somedomain.com
```

It is being redirected to **localhost** - the default IIS8 page - which is the wwwroot folder on windows. Great!

However the followings don't work:

```
somedomain.com:8081
nor
127.0.0.1:8081
```

Anyway to make it work?

P.S
ASP.NET Web API doesn't work very well with localhost address (for instance you cannot add cookies from the server for localhost address).

Comment: Are you _sure_ that you're actually listening to port 8081? From your problem description, it seems that nothing is actually running there. Check again.

Comment: Thanks, but as the first URI indicates, http://localhost:8081/api/customers works great, but:
http://somedomain.com:8081/api/customer, does not.

Comment: Weird. Where does your webapp think it lives then? Might it be that it redirects/doesn't answer if you don't call it as "localhost"? The fact that it won't answer at 127.0.0.1 could indicate something of that sort.